# Propagating multiple make commands

Tags: c, makefile, gnu

I have a makefile that essentially looks like this:

```
testa:
  make -C dog/ testa
  make -C cat/ testa
testb:
  make -C dog/ testb
  make -C cat/ testb
```

With multiple folders 1...10. When I run 'make testa' at the top level it goes through all the subdirectories one by one and runs the command 'make testa' on all the folders below. Is there a better way to do this instead of having several lines of the same `make -C folderx/ testy`?
Thanks

Comment: Tried `make -C folder*/ testa` ?

Comment: Oh the names are not generic folder1, folder2 names. I'll rename the folder names to clarify

Comment: Well, you could use a variable, e.g. `SUBDIRS = dog cat elephant etc` and then `testa: ${SUBDIRS}` `${SUBDIRS}: make -C $@ testa`

Answer (score 1):

You can decouple the target names from the subdirectories by using [target-specific values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
testa: TARG:=testa
testb: TARG:=testb

testa testb:
    make -C dog/ $(TARG)
    make -C cat/ $(TARG)
```

and then delegate the work to targets named after the subdirectories:

```
testa: TARG:=testa
testb: TARG:=testb

SUBDIRS := dog cat

testa testb: $(SUBDIRS)

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)
 $(SUBDIRS):
        make -C $@ $(TARG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
TARGETS := testa testb
DIRS := dog cat

define TARGETS_TO_DIRS

$(foreach target, $1, $(eval $(target): $(addsuffix /$(target), $2)))
$(foreach dir, $2, $(foreach target, $1, $(dir)/$(target))):
    $(MAKE) -C $$(@D) $$(@F)

endef

$(eval $(call TARGETS_TO_DIRS, $(TARGETS), $(DIRS)))
```